# Uable to connect to telnet socket properly

Tags: java, telnet

I'm trying to connect to telnet server but when I connect to telnet server running on port 9999. but when I run this code. it shows welcome message but then no command works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    final String server = "erdos.dsm.fordham.edu";
    final int port = 9999;

    Socket sock = null;
     PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        sock = new Socket(server,port);
        sock.setKeepAlive(true);

        out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Hangman.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {

        System.out.println(in.readLine());

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s =  scanner.nextLine();
        s = s.toUpperCase();
    while(!s.equals("QUIT"))
    {

        out.print(s);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println(in.read());
         s =  scanner.nextLine();
    }   
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing bye");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Hangman.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED : See first version via answer previous version**

That's creepy, but it works. Because I wasn't able to find a terminaison for the incoming data after a command, I decided to add a Runnable+Thread that reads and a method in it that take what has been read by waiting 100ms (or more if necessary) before considering the whole data was received.

```
package base_test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        final String server = "erdos.dsm.fordham.edu";
        final int port = 9999;

        Socket sock = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            sock = new Socket(server, port);
            sock.setKeepAlive(true);

            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // Logger.getLogger(Hangman.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
            // ex);
        }

        //Start a different that listen to incoming data
        DataReader dr = new DataReader(in);
        Thread dataThread = new Thread(dr);
        dataThread.start();


        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = "";
            do {
                System.out.println(dr.getLastData());

                s = scanner.nextLine();
                s = s.toUpperCase();
                if (s.isEmpty())
                    continue;

                out.println(s);
            } while (!s.equals("QUIT"));
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing bye");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // Logger.getLogger(Hangman.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,
            // ex);
        }
    }
}
```

DataReader class :

```
package base_test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DataReader implements Runnable {

    private final int MAX_WAITING_LOOPS = 100;

    private LinkedList<StringBuilder> receivedData = new LinkedList<>();
    private BufferedReader in;
    private boolean isWaiting = true;
    private boolean isReceiving = false;

    public DataReader(BufferedReader in) {
        this.in = in;
        receivedData.push(new StringBuilder());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        do {
            try {
                isWaiting = true;

                char last = (char)in.read();
                StringBuilder sb = receivedData.peek();
                sb.append(last);

                isWaiting = false;
                isReceiving = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } while (true);
    }

    public String getLastData() throws InterruptedException {
        int loopCount = 0;

        while (loopCount < MAX_WAITING_LOOPS) {
            if (isReceiving == false || isWaiting == false) {
                //System.out.println("===RESET");
                loopCount = 0;
            } else {
                loopCount++;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }

        isReceiving = false;

        receivedData.push(new StringBuilder());
        StringBuilder sb = receivedData.pollLast();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works very fine but does not read the whole line for example if I type help It will just return first line

Comment: Yeah. I know, because there is a line skipped between the first line and the others. Did you code the server part ?

Comment: The line terminator in Telnet is `\r\n`, not `\n`. You aren't testing for `readLine()` returning null, and the test for a blank line seems pointless.

Comment: I agree! That's why my current version (not posted) is by reading char by char, but it never happens that `\r\n` is returned. I don't think it can return null though. I don't think it's a properly defined TELNET server. Using `\r\n` on the end of commands doesn't work at all.

Comment: because as I know escape string is C-] or Ctrl ]

Comment: One of your colleague ? Do you have access to change it ? Because it seems to be pretty buggy.

Comment: I got a functional version. It is still not perfect, but seems to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112196/discussion-between-naveed-khan-and-master-djon).

Comment: Did you the latest version ?